# Send an email a month after order is "complete"?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, email, cron, order-status

I neeed a recommendation on what's the best way to send an email 1 month after order is completed (it's an email that asks to review the product).

Should I use cronjob and check every day for orders that were created 1 month earlier? Or is there more elegant solution?

Comment: I would go with the cron approach. Everything that is automated should go through a cron. And a tip: write an observer that saves the date when the order became complete. Do not rely on the `updated_at` column or any column from the order history table because you may get errors or you might sent the same e-mail twice.

Comment: Thx, I'll go with cron then. I'm using this technique to find order "complete" date - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128750/how-to-get-completion-date-of-an-order-in-magento , do you see any flaws in it?

Comment: You can get easily the order(complete) details..But you should aware of creating CronJob .. The problem is sending emails. If you have lot of completed (eg 1000) orders with in a day, then you need to send 1000 emails. So your server may go down. If you hosted your site in shared host, then definitely the hosting peoples down your site.. So be aware of this ..

Comment: @Marvin3 did you ever complete this?

Comment: I also had to build something like that. We run our cron every hour, so there should be no problem with the server.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

1. create a new `order(_item)` attribute
2. write a cron job which checks for `attribute IS NULL`
3. write mail for all of the orders
4. set the `attribute = 1`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's number of extension that remind customer to revisit store, write a review and whatnot. Pretty much all of them are commercial though, so I won't paste any of them here, you have to find them yourself (vanilla Magento doesn't have such functionality). All of them require use of linux/unix/os x cron service.