# Send automatic mail after completed order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, programmatically

I would like to send my customers a mail, after a week, when the order has been completed.

Can someone help me? (Magento 1.9.2).

I also found a [topic](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18980/send-an-email-a-month-after-order-is-complete) about this issue, but it is not updated for a while.

My code for so far:

**Config.xml**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Productreviews_Productreview>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Productreviews_Productreview>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <cronexample>
        <class>Productreviews_Productreview_Helper</class>
      </cronexample>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <cronexample>
        <class>Productreviews_Productreview_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>cronexample_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </cronexample>
    </models>
  </global>    
    <crontab>
        <jobs>            
            <send_productreview>
                <schedule><cron_expr>5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>cronexample/cron::cronSendReviewMail</model></run>
            </send_productreview>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

**Cron.php:**

```
<?php
class Productreviews_Productreview_Model_Cron{   
    public function cronSendReviewMail(){
        Mage::log("Cron Test ".now(),null,"mageCronExample.log");

$time = time();
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 604800; // 60*60*7*24
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);

$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->setPageSize(5)
->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('==' => array('complete')));

                foreach ($order_collection as $item) {
                    // echo $item->getId();

                    $sendtoemail = $item->getShippingAddress()->getEmail();

                    $idid = $item->getIncrementId();
                    $order = $item->loadByIncrementId($idid);
                    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

                        // EMAIL LAYOUT
                        $email = 'Email content here';

                            // EMAIL VERSTUREN
                            $to      = $sendtoemail;
                            $subject = 'Subject';
                            $headers = 'From: x@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                                'Reply-To: x@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
                            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

                            mail($to, $subject, $email, $headers);      
                }

    }
}
```

Comment: you want to send mail immediate after order complete or after a week of order complete.

Comment: Customers should receive a mail after a week of order complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to use cron which will execute on daily basis and fetch order data, depending upon **created_at** field of collection, you can decide the order of your required duration some thing like all orders whose **created_at** value is less than a week and order status is complete. for this you can use the following code.

```
$time = time();
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 604800; // 60*60*7*24
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);
$order_items = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $from))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE))
    ->load();
```

and to create a cron you can follow the following tutorials.

http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited the code and it is working fine. However, is there a way to start the cron after the order has been completed? Finally, it needs to be like: order finished at 01-05-2016 --> customer receives a mail at 07-05-16. Thanks!

Comment: For this difference just replace the **604800**  in line `$lastTime = $time - 604800; // 60*60*7*24`  with **518400** this will provide you the exact record. for testing you can try `$time = strtotime('2016-05-07');
echo '<br> TO - '.$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 518400; // 60*60*7*24
echo '<br>FROM - '.$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);`

Comment: Thank you again. However, you stated that the cron needs to be executed on **daily basis** and completed order date is set to **7 days**. Is this the right way to do this? Because customers will receive a mail again on day 2 now. I also added the my code above now.

Comment: How? firstly on day 2 difference is going to be 8 days so this order is not going to select on second days and you can use custom table which stores last order processed by the cron and add a condition to not to select order for which emails are already sended.

Answer (score 0):

Me too faced this same situation.
I solved with Following Code:

Create a file called `sendmail.php` in root folder with the following code:

```
require_once ("app/Mage.php");
ini_set("error_reporting",E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",true);
umask(0);|
Mage::app('admin');
$time = time();
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 604800; // 60*60*7*24
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);
$lastweek = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-7 days"));
//Get Completed Order Collection placed in last one week 
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $lastweek .' 00:00:00', 'to' => $lastweek. ' 23:59:59'))
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));
foreach($orders as $order)  
{
    $order_incr_id = base64_encode($order->getIncrementId());

    $template = 38;// Template Id, You Can Get from System Config too
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $store_name = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getName();
    $website_id = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($order->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId();
    $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website_id);
    $website_name = strtolower($website->getName());
    $template = Mage::getStoreConfig('statuschange_options/quote_email/rating_template');
    $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

    $mailSuccess = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->setDesignConfig(
        array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId))
            ->sendTransactional(
                $template,
                $sender,
                $order->getCustomerEmail(),
                $order->getCustomerFirstname(),
                array(
                //You Can Add Any Parameters to be Passed in the mail
                    'sender'  => $senderName,
                    'username' => $order->getCustomerFirstname(),
                    'order_id' => $order->getIncrementId(),
                    'storename' => $website_name,
                    'customer_id' => $order->getCustomerId(),
                    'order_incr_id' => $order_incr_id
                    )
            );

            if($mailSuccess){
                // If mail Sent it will be Logged with Customer name, Order Id and Mail Id
                Mage::log('Mail sent. OrderId: '. $order->getIncrementId().' '.'Customer Name: '.$order->getCustomerFirstname().' '.$order->getCustomerLastname().' '.'MailId: '. $order->getCustomerEmail()
                , null, $lastweek.'-'.'MailSent.log');
            }
            else {
                // If mail Not Sent it will be Logged with Customer name, Order Id and Mail Id
                Mage::log('Mail not sent. OrderId: '. $order->getIncrementId().' '.'Customer Name: '.$order->getCustomerFirstname().' '.$order->getCustomerLastname().' '.'MailId: '.$order->getCustomerEmail()
                , null, $lastweek.'MailNotSent.log');
            }
            }
```

**Note:**

You Need to Set in Cron File to Run when it to be run. I set it to run in the `11:55:00 PM`